# Generic way to hide install plugin link from wp-admin

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I want to hide the install plugin link from  wp-admin menubar in generic way . ie which ever plugin the user will install in future will not be visible to user in menubar . is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'Plugins' menu item from the wp-admin dashboard by adding the below code to function.php in your theme,

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );               

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

By this you can hide the menu from user. (But page can be directly accessed)

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

or if you want to remove submenu page from menu list, see the code at https://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page

Comment: the above code is hidding only plugin link but i want to hide installed plugin link